# Use grep for total count of string found inside file directory

Tags: string, bash, unix, count, grep

I know that `grep -c 'string' dir` returns a list of file names and the number of times that string appeared in each respective file.

Is there any way to simply get the total count of the string appearing in the entire file directory using grep (or possibly manipulating this output)? Thank you.

```
BASH_DIR=$(awk -F "=" '/Bash Dir/ {print $2}' bash_input.txt)

FIND_COUNT=0

for f in "$BASH_DIR"/*.sh
do
    f=$(basename $f)

    #Read through job files
    echo -e "$f: $(cat * | grep -c './$f')"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit julienc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to look in files ending in `.sh`, use

```
grep -c pattern *.sh
```

or if you want it stored in a variable, use

```
n=$(grep -c xyz *.sh)
```

Comment: I keep getting an out put of "cat: Datamart: Is a directory
yieldCalculator.sh: 7"

Comment: I assume you have directories as well as files in there? If you want to count the occurrences of strings in all your `.sh` files, just use `cat *.sh` in place of `cat *`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one of them is by using `awk`:

```
grep -c 'string' dir | awk -F: '{ s+=$2 } END { print s }'
```

`awk` will get the number of occurences in each file from the output of `grep` and print the sum.

Comment: feel free to add -r to grep.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` with `-exec cat` and `grep -c string`:

```
find /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f  -exec cat {} + | grep -c conf
139
```

So there are 139 occurrence of string 'conf' on my /etc.

Mind you that I didn't want to run recursively otherwise I would remove `-maxdepth 1`